# Division and Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, divisibility, gaussian-integers

Let $2-3i,5+2i,a+bi\in\mathbb Z[i]$ (Gaussian integers).Prove that if $(2-3i)|(a+bi)$ and $(5+2i)|(a+bi)$, then $(2-3i)(5+2i)|(a+bi)$.

Solution (attempt):

As $(2-3i)|(a+bi),$ then there exist $(c+di)$ such that $a+bi=(2-3i)(c+di).$

And as $(5+2i)|(a+bi),$ then there exist $(p+qi)$ such that $a+bi=(5+2i)(p+qi).$

Thus $(2-3i)(c+di)=(5+2i)(p+qi),$ for some $c,d,p,q\in\mathbb Z[i]$.

Then what can I do to show this $a+bi=(x+yi)(2-3i)(5+2i),$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z[i]?$

Comment: $N(2-3i)=13$ and $N(5+2i)=29$, so $2-3i$ and $5+2i$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Please give some context. Do you know that they enjoy gcds or unique factorization or closely related properties?

Comment: @BillDubuque context? they enjoy gcd? I don't know what do you mean

Comment: What arithmetical properties do you know about the ring R of Gaussian integers? Do you know R is a Euclidean or gcd domain, or a UFD?

Comment: @BillDubuque it is an euclidean domain, what is UFD ?. Arithmetical properties: I think all properties of $\mathbb C$ holds for $G[i]$.

Comment: Google UFD. So do you know that Euclidean domains, just like $\Bbb Z$ enjoy Bezout's identity for gcds, so irreducibles are prime, so factorizations into irreducibles are unique, so they are UFDs, etc?  If so then the proof should be clear - just mimic the proof for integers, after  you prove they are coprime (having coprime norms)

Comment: @BillDubuque they are coprimes because of the first comment, right?.So do I prove it for integers and then I just make a 'substitution'. i.e. I should write (a+bi) instead of the integers?

Comment: In a Euclidean domain $D$, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, i.e., $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, implies $ab\mid c$. Try as example $D=\Bbb{Z}$ and then adapt the proof to the case $D=\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Xam I think that is what I did, I follow the proof for $\mathbb Z$, and the I just make a substitution, i.e. $a=(2-3i),b=(5+2i)$. Do you think is this correct or am I wrong?

Comment: How did you proved that $2-3i$ and $5+2i$ are coprime?

Comment: @Xam I just apply the result (the last line) of the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall z,w \in \mathbb Z[i], |zw| = |z||w|$

$|zw|^2 = |z|^2|w|^2$

and $|z|^2 \in \mathbb Z$

if $|z|^2$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$ then $z$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$